# How do I use SimpleExpression.eqAny in the mysema framework?

Tags: java, querydsl, mysema

I'm looking at filtering in my query to return entities where `locations` intersects with the queries locations. From the method signature it seems that the `eqAny` method is the way to go.

The only downside is that it doesn't accept a collection, but only a CollectionExpression. How do I create a CollectionExpression from my collection?

My (non compiling) code is along these lines:

```
import com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanExpression;
//…
StringPath locations = … //irrelevant
BooleanExpression predicate = anotherPredicate.and(qbuilder.locations.eqAny(query.getLocations().orElse(new HashSet<>())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you found a solution after so long, however, as I faced the same issue (and could not find any help on how to do it), I post my own solution in case someone is in the same place.

First, let's suppose my class is the following,

```
public class MyClass {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    // All the Getters, Setters, Constructors, etc
}
```

As a result, the **equivalent auto-generated QueryDSL class** will be `QMyClass`

What I did is to **manually create my BooleanExpression by iterating through my Collection**, something like the following (let's suppose the collections are `List<String> ids` and `List<String> names`),

```
QMyClass myClass = QMyClass.myClass;

BooleanExpression be = null;

if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(ids)) {
   be = myClass.id.equalsIgnoreCase(ids.get(0));
   if (ids.size() > 1) {
       for (int i = 1; i < ids.size(); i++) {
           be = be.or(myClass.id.equalsIgnoreCase(ids.get(i)));
       }
   }
}

if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(names)) {
   be = be.and(myClass.name.equalsIgnoreCase(names.get(0)));
   if (names.size() > 1) {
      for (int i = 1; i < names.size(); i++) {
          be = be.or(myClass.name.equalsIgnoreCase(names.get(i)));
      }
   }
}
```

After that, the rest was easy. I simply had to extend MyClassRepository interface as following (in order to take advantage of QueryDSL functionalities),

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Serializable>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor {

...

}
```

Finally, I used the **findAll** Repository method (extended now of course by default due to QueryDSL) as following (I used a Pageable as well for my case but that's optional of course),

```
Page<MyClass> myClassList = this.myClassRepository(be, pageable);
```